# xsl templates or one long file

Tags: templates, xslt

I am creating by xsl file listing of data, which is long, because it should show different output in different cases. To achieve it I use element `<xsl:choose>`.
File is so long, I will not post it, because my question is not so connected with code, but with performance.
I just took out differences in code for each case and create from them templates.
I leave main conditional test, but instead of long code between `<xsl:when>` I call template.
Everything work well, so my question is, how is it with performance. From point of speed is better to have so long file with code, or templates, which are called in case, test is positive?
...just I call that template only in one file, I do not use them on multiple places.

Really thank you for answer Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write with a style that facilitates current understanding and future maintainability.  The tiny speed difference between calling a template and in-lining output is almost certainly not going to matter in end-to-end performance.  Favor pattern matching (*applying* templates) over *calling* templates procedurally -- it's more aligned with XSLT's natural declarative style.

**Performance is nearly never a concern with XSLT.**  In the dozens of systems I've built across several sectors, XSLT has never become a bottleneck despite often being on a critical path.  Focus on correctness and clarity and only worry about performance if you receive hard data indicating that it's an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. So I will use templates, sounds good because If I need change something take significant time even I use notes to find it, because some codes are very similar.